# Where can I find XML schema definitions (XSD) for JSF Facelets tag libraries?

Tags: jsf, xsd, facelets

Where can I find XML schema definitions for

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

or since JSF 2.2

```
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" 
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" 
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
```

?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6594482 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19027595

Answer (score 6):

I recently found puzzling lack of XSD for JSF tags. Although such XSD would not be complete reference as described [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/faces-api/issues/489) I find it still useful. They can help avoid typos and provide documentation for tags and attributes.

Therefore I transformed available `taglib.xml` files to XSD files. The result is available [on my GitHub project](https://github.com/destin/jsf-goodies/tree/master/jsf_xsd). Available XSLT transform can be used to generate XSD from any `*.taglib.xml` file.

In IntelliJ IDEA Community those XSDs work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

In the jar-file of your JSF implementation there is a `META-INF` folder. There you can find the `.tld` files that you need. But they are not `.xsd`.

Note that if you are using facelets, the facelets definitions are in the `jsf-facelets-xx.jar`

As for the JSTL core tags - [this is a useful reference](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/)

That is all about JSF pre-2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the .tld files from @Bozho's answer to XSD files to integrate into an Schema Aware XML Editor [Details](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2008/03/facelets-and-xsd-converted-tlds.html)

If you happen to use IntelliJ, you can add the JSF facet to your module, and the IDE will provide autocomplete and documentation for elements and attributes in the JSF namespaces, based directly on the .tld files.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ but it complains for:  xmlns:common="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/common but not others like xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"... Any help?