# Eclipse - Can't find facelet tag library for uri http://java.sun.com/jsf/html

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, facelets

In my `index.xhtml` , I have a namespace defined like this `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"`. The server at this url indicates that the page [cannot be found](http://java.sun.com/jsf/html).

Do you know where the page has moved ?

**Eclipse Info**

```
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For solving this problem this is what I did :

```
     1. Close the eclipse project
     2. Open the eclipse project
     3. Right click on the project
     4. Click on Validate

   => The (false) warnings are gone.
```

Comment: This works for me only in situation when JSF implementation is on the project's classpath (API is not enough). Otherwise, error still exists. For details take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25402146/1037316).

Comment: This worked for me. So, why is this happening? Something wrong with the validator?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop I don't know. However, you can file an issue to Eclipse team.

Answer (score 5):

The XML taglib namespace URI does not point to a real web resource or something. It just points to the same value as the `<namespace>` entry of the `.taglib.xml` file of the XML taglib in question in the runtime classpath, which in case of JSF taglibs (and lot others) *just* happens to be a HTTP URL. In case of Mojarra, you can find the declaration in the `/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/html_basic.taglib.xml` file of the `jsf-impl.jar` file.

If you're encountering problems with referencing JSF HTML tags, then the cause lies somewhere else.

Comment: Actually I'm facing this problem : Description Resource 
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages index.xhtml (...) Facelet Validator

Comment: That's a Glassfish/Eclipse specific issue. Try cleaning the project (*Project > Clean*). It's after all just an Eclipse project build warning. The code should run without trouble. Real JSF runtime errors are more of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers were useful to me. Here I provide an alternative way for solving this issue. I fixed this problem by adding the jar `primefaces-[version].jar` to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: Which jar did you add ?

Comment: primefaces-[version].jar

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@taglib   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
```

jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar jar in your lib.

Comment: -1: OP is using Facelets, not legacy JSP. Also, the problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the Uri respective to the jsf version you are using.

```
. The real JSTL 1.0 taglib uses the URI *http://java.sun.com/jstl/core.*
. The real JSTL 1.1/1.2 taglib uses the URI *http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core*.
. Facelets 1.x uses the URI *http://java.sun.com/jstl/core.*
. Facelets 2.x uses the URI *http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.*
. Facelets 2.2+ uses the URI *http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core.*
```