# How does xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" work?

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-1.2

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594482/eclipse-cant-find-facelet-tag-library-for-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsf-html), I tried to find out `html_basic.taglib.xml` file in jsf-impl.jar (as per answer from BalusC). There doesn't exist any xml file `html_basic.taglib.xml`. However, there are other xml files like `jsf-ri-runtime.xml, xml.xsd` which doesn't have entry for the URL in question.

Since I didn't get the required xml file and required entry for the URL I counldn't actually understand what BalusC tried to tell in that post. Can anyone please elaborate on the same? And where can I find the xml files in JSF jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer applies to JSF 2.0, not to JSF 1.2.

In JSF 1.2, which does not support Facelets natively, there's no means of any `.taglib.xml` file in the `jsf-impl.jar`. There are only JSP-specific `.tld` files. For Facelets in JSF 1.2, it's instead enclosed in `jsf-facelets.jar`. It's located in `/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml`, which in turn contains solely the following entry:

```
<facelet-taglib>
    <library-class>com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.html.HtmlLibrary</library-class>
</facelet-taglib>
```

[You can find here the source code of `HtmlLibrary`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/html/HtmlLibrary.java.html).