# How can I create jsf tag library descriptor in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, file, jsf

I'm new to eclipse and java EE 
How can I create jsf tag library descriptor in eclipse?
best.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: [eclipse-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481429/eclipse-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsf-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create TLD file manually and add it to the project.
Example TLD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<taglib>
 <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
 <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
 <shortname>javaonline</shortname>
 <info>Sample Tag library  Created for javaonlineguide</info>
  <!-Tag Starts -->
 <tag>
    <name>ipaddress</name>
    <tagclass>javaonline.IpAddress </tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
    <info>
       This is a example tag for displaying ipaddress.
    </info>
    <attribute>
    <name>target</name>
    <required>false</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
     </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

You need to copy TLD files in the WEB-INF directory or in a subdirectory of WEB-INF so that the application can access.

If you need detailed [step-by-step guide](http://javaonlineguide.net/2014/10/easy-steps-to-create-custom-tags-in-jsp-example-code-tutorial.html), you check [this one](http://javaonlineguide.net/2014/10/easy-steps-to-create-custom-tags-in-jsp-example-code-tutorial.html).

Comment: thanks. I mean does eclipse have menu to create taglib template file and I  write my own tags or I should manually create one and paste it to my project?

Comment: You need to do it manually and add it to the project.