# Eclipse can't find JSF 2.2 taglibs

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I am using JSF 2.2 taglibs but Eclipse is displaying the following warning message:

> Can't find facelet tag library for uri http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf

What bugs me is that I've faced this issue before and it was related to classpath JARs, but now it is only affecting JSF 2.2 tag libs.

Taglib `xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"` is working fine, the warning is shown to JSF 2.2 specifics like `"/jsf"` and `"/jsf/passthrough"`. Here is an image showing warnings for JSF 2.2. tag libs, but prior namespaces are loaded correctly.

[image: Warnings for JSF 2.2 tag libs]

I have tried to solve the issue with help of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6594482/3231778) but none of the procedures (clean, restart, close/open, validate, etc) have worked for me.

Dependencies for JSF (derived from WildFly 10.1 pom.xml):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13.SP1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse info:

```
Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200
```

## Update

After looking into the taglib files I found no "passthrough" or "friendly markup" reference. So there is no surprise Eclipse won't find it...

There is no file under `com.sun.faces.metadata.taglib` for Friendly Markup and Passthrough, for both Glassfish and JBoss implementations.

[image]

The question now is where should these files be?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project in addition of validating & restarting.. ?

Comment: Have you tried updating the eclipse project config from maven so the libs are included? Do you have the jsf facets enabled? Etc...

Comment: @Omar yes, tried cleaning the project and updating the Maven project as well. I'll increment my question.

Comment: @Kukeltje the libs are included. Eclipse is loading other taglibs, like the core, only JSF 2.2 taglibs seem to be missing. Yes JSF  and Web facets are enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Update:*** opened issue [WFLY-9579](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9579)

It seems that the taglib files are missing from the implementation JARs, for both Glassfish and JBoss projects. I hope to be wrong but I found no other explanation.

[image]

I've posted a thread so this behavior can be investigated.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274046

### Workaround

To stop the IDE from warning simply create empty taglibs files and associate to the `web.xml`. Files should go under `/WEB-INF/` and have the appropriate extension `taglib.xml`.

The JSF implementation will behave normally and should process the facelets correctly.

*friendly_markup.taglib.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <namespace>http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf</namespace>
</facelet-taglib>
```

*passthrough.taglib.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <namespace>http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough</namespace>
</facelet-taglib>
```

*web.xml*

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/passthrough.taglib.xml;/WEB-INF/friendly_markup.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here is what it looks like. Now the warnings are gone (and my OCD is calm again). I would like to try and make JAR dependency for it, if I find some spare time.

[image]