# JSF2: How are the *.taglib.xml files discovered in jsf-impl.jar?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, taglib

In `jsf-impl.jar` (which can be found on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0-m03)), the `*.taglib.xml` files are located in directory `com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/`.

I don't understand how they're discovered in this case, because chapter 10.3.2 of the [JSF 2 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) says:

> ### 10.3.2 Facelet Tag Library mechanism
>
> ...
>
> The run time must support two modes of discovery for Facelet tag library descriptors
>
> - Via declaration in the web.xml, as specified in Section 11.1.3 “Application Configuration Parameters”
> - Via auto discovery by placing the tag library descriptor file within a jar on the web application classpath, naming the file so that it ends with `“.taglib.xml”`, without the quotes, and placing the file in the `META-INF` directory in the
>     jar file.
>
> ...

Here, they're not located in directory `META-INF`, so how does it work?

Note: in `META-INF`, they are some `.tld` files, but I'm not interested in them since I'm not using JSP as the view, but Facelets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't using the `taglib.xml` for that. It's programmatically registering them via [`com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.html.HtmlLibrary`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jsf/html/HtmlLibrary.java#HtmlLibrary) in [`com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationAssociate.java#ApplicationAssociate) which is executed during startup. Here are the relevant lines from Mojarra 2.2.1 (copypasted from [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationAssociate.java#954)):

```
954        c.addTagLibrary(new CoreLibrary());
955        c.addTagLibrary(new CoreLibrary(CoreLibrary.XMLNSNamespace));
956        c.addTagLibrary(new HtmlLibrary());
957        c.addTagLibrary(new HtmlLibrary(HtmlLibrary.XMLNSNamespace));
958        c.addTagLibrary(new UILibrary());
959        c.addTagLibrary(new UILibrary(UILibrary.XMLNSNamespace));
960        c.addTagLibrary(new JstlCoreLibrary());
961        c.addTagLibrary(new JstlCoreLibrary(JstlCoreLibrary.IncorrectNamespace));
962        c.addTagLibrary(new JstlCoreLibrary(JstlCoreLibrary.XMLNSNamespace));
963        c.addTagLibrary(new PassThroughAttributeLibrary());
964        c.addTagLibrary(new PassThroughElementLibrary());
965        c.addTagLibrary(new FunctionLibrary(JstlFunction.class, FunctionLibrary.Namespace));
966        c.addTagLibrary(new FunctionLibrary(JstlFunction.class, FunctionLibrary.XMLNSNamespace));
967        if (isDevModeEnabled()) {
968            c.addTagLibrary(new FunctionLibrary(DevTools.class, DevTools.Namespace));
969            c.addTagLibrary(new FunctionLibrary(DevTools.class, DevTools.NewNamespace));
970        }
971        c.addTagLibrary(new CompositeLibrary());
972        c.addTagLibrary(new CompositeLibrary(CompositeLibrary.XMLNSNamespace));
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a reason for doing this programmatically, rather than using the `taglib.xml`?

Comment: The reason is because it's a container-JAR, not an user-JAR. The taglib.xml works only for user-provided JARs in /WEB-INF/lib.